# How can Young's double slit experiment explain the wave nature of light?

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment

I've been reading about wave theory of light and the famous experiment performed by Thomas Young. But how does this experiment prove that light is a wave ?

Comment: Do you know what diffraction and interference is?

Comment: Er ... the wave nature of light explains the results of the experiment, not the other way around. The experiment *supports* an understanding of light as waves.